# Cyclic subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

Q: If $f(x) = x+1$, describe the subgroup $\langle f \rangle$ of $S_\mathbb R$.

So for $f$ to be the generator wouldn't we continue to build starting with $f$ so $x+1$ and then $x+1+1=x+2$ and so on?

Comment: What is $S_R$ in this context?

Comment: Permutations (bijection) of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: I edited my question. I hadn't realized I'd marked it with just R, it's meant to be the reals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the subgroup would consist of functions of the form $f(x)=x+t$ where $t \in \Bbb Z$.